# Icon design for "I´m going" and "I´m interested" buttons

Tags: buttons, icons

I am developing an Android application to display a list of upcoming events nearby. When click on a list item, the application display some event info, and also two buttons:

```
The first button represents "I am attending"
The second button represents "I am interested"
```

Those buttons should display the count of all attending/interested people and its respective value("I am attending"/"I am interested")

My questions are:

```
1.-Should I make an icon to represent the button?
2.-Is it OK to display "attending" instead of "I´m attending"?
3.-Should I add some decoration to the uploaded image? (Gradients, etc...)
4.-Is the uploaded image user-friendly? (easy to understand...)
```

I am talking about a button like this:

[image: Button]

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, as it is about icon design.

Comment: 1. and 2. are not off-topic. Is there any way you can reword the question so that it's not about the specifics about the design and more on the sides of the interaction?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey the question isn't about the design of an icon, but instead is about whether to use an icon or not.

Comment: After rereading, I would agree it is about the use of rather then the design of.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a confusion between several elements:

- **Action** and **current state**: the button is supposed to allow me to RSVP as "Attending". But it also shows the *current* number of people attending. Is it a button or just a label?
- **I** and **others**: so the button shows that 18 are attending. How do I add myself as an attendee? I'm supposed to click a button that's meant for others? Where's my button?

Also, the image you've uploaded **doesn't look like a button**, so it's very hard to tell that's the element that I should interact with.

You don't need icons or gradients: **just use words**, and seperate the current state ("18 attendees") and the possible action ("Are you attending? Yes/No") and synchronize the two accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.-Should I make an icon to represent the button?

Icons can be really confusing, ambiguous, and they add to the time it takes the user to interpret the design. The general recommendation is that if you can say it with words - you should. You should definitely not base the interface on icons only, but you may consider adding them next to the text.

Like anything in UX - it depends and there are exceptions. Icons can add to the aesthetics of the design, albeit while adding visual noise. Also, if there aren't many icons, experienced users may get accustomed to them and may locate a function by the icon rather than text. But the interpretation time for a single word is typically similar to that of an icon - so no real gain here if the label is one word.

> 2.-Is it OK to display "attending" instead of "I´m attending"?

Yes it is. It is implicit that you are the one to attend and no one else. That's why you don't see buttons labelled "I'm OK with this" but just plain "OK".

> 3.-Should I add some decoration to the uploaded image? (Gradients, etc...)

Refrain from adding any graphics unless it serves a clear purpose. Gradients, in general, add visual noise while not helping with any semantics. Even their aesthetic is now heavily disputed in the age of flat design.

> 4.-Is the uploaded image user-friendly? (easy to understand...)

I don't understand what is the uploaded image and how is it differ from the icon. Also, is your plan to put the number of people attending on the same button saying "attending"/"interested"? Because that may be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The naming of these buttons is crappy. I'm attending also means I'm interested! Do I click both of them? What happens if I'm just interested?

Also, if one button says "18 attending" and other says "I'm interested", it'll be normal for me to think that clicking "I'm interested" will add me to the list! After all the other is just giving info, how do I know it'll do something! How do I know it's a button!

I'm assuming the intended functions these buttons are:

- **I'm attending** for sure.
- **I'm interested** but not sure if I'll go. Ask me later or save to some sort of wishlist.

Take inspiration from this and always name the buttons according to the function they'll perform:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1EVLV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If you think my suggestion is changing more things than acceptable, I'm happy to discuss.

And no gradients. They're a 90's thing.